# How to add default gateway with trailing zero(s)?

Tags: networking, dhcp

In my office I want to connect my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop to ethernet. All my colleagues are using Windows 10 laptops without any problems, I am the only guy with an Ubuntu laptop.

The DHCP server returns a default gateway of 192.168.2.0. But my laptop does not accept this gateway. When I try to add the default gateway I get the following error message:

```
sudo route add default gw 192.168.2.0 dev eth0
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable
```

Output from dhclient:

```
sudo dhclient -v eth0
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/eth0/28:f1:0e:0a:de:34
Sending on   LPF/eth0/28:f1:0e:0a:de:34
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.169 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x6bb234ba)
DHCPACK of 192.168.2.169 from 192.168.2.0
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
bound to 192.168.2.169 -- renewal in 14325 seconds.
```

Wireshark capture of dhcp ACK packet:

```
Frame 6: 342 bytes on wire (2736 bits), 342 bytes captured (2736 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Lancom_2a:35:48 (xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.2.0, Dst: 255.255.255.255
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 67, Dst Port: 68
Bootstrap Protocol (ACK)
    Message type: Boot Reply (2)
    Hardware type: Ethernet (0x01)
    Hardware address length: 6
    Hops: 0
    Transaction ID: 0x4b1a125c
    Seconds elapsed: 0
    Bootp flags: 0x0000 (Unicast)
        0... .... .... .... = Broadcast flag: Unicast
        .000 0000 0000 0000 = Reserved flags: 0x0000
    Client IP address: 0.0.0.0
    Your (client) IP address: 192.168.2.169
    Next server IP address: 192.168.2.0
    Relay agent IP address: 0.0.0.0
    Client MAC address: Dell_0a:de:34 (28:f1:0e:0a:de:34)
    Client hardware address padding: 00000000000000000000
    Server host name not given
    Boot file name not given
    Magic cookie: DHCP
    Option: (53) DHCP Message Type (ACK)
        Length: 1
        DHCP: ACK (5)
    Option: (54) DHCP Server Identifier
        Length: 4
        DHCP Server Identifier: 192.168.2.0
    Option: (1) Subnet Mask
        Length: 4
        Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
    Option: (3) Router
        Length: 4
        Router: 192.168.2.0
    Option: (6) Domain Name Server
        Length: 4
        Domain Name Server: 192.168.2.0
    Option: (15) Domain Name
        Length: 6
        Domain Name: intern
    Option: (28) Broadcast Address
        Length: 4
        Broadcast Address: 192.168.2.255
    Option: (51) IP Address Lease Time
        Length: 4
        IP Address Lease Time: (30000s) 8 hours, 20 minutes
    Option: (255) End
        Option End: 255
    Padding: 000000000000000000000000
```

Output of command `ipconfig /all` on a windows laptop connected to the same network:

```
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : intern
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.9(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Freitag, 30. August 2019 09:15:13
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Freitag, 30. August 2019 23:59:39
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.0
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.0
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.0
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Comment: I understand that you are claiming that the Windows 10 systems work with this fine.  Have you actually got a output of one of the Windows 10 systems by running `ipconfig /all` and looked at the info?  192.168.2.0 is a subnet ID address and not the IP address on a 255.255.255.0 subnet.  The only time 192.168.2.0 could even be a valid IP is if the network was 192.168.0.0 with a subnet mask of 255.255.252.0.  You might want to check also with whoever setup the network about it.  Also see http://www.subnet-calculator.com/subnet.php?net_class=A as it will show you how IP4 networking works.

Comment: I added the output of ipconfig.

Comment: It looks as though the network is setup incorrectly so the only way that you are going to get on is to either use a Windows 10 connection (way to go Microsoft for allowing invalid IP addresses) or have the network fixed to the correct IP4 setup.

Comment: There is one other possibility of trying to setup a static IP of one that won't conflict with any others on the network then using a 192.168.0.0 subnet ID with a 255.255.252.0 subnet mask then adding the gateway of 192.168.2.0 would now be valid, but it still might have issues with routing.

Comment: If I try to add the route as @Terrance mentioned I get the following error:
`sudo route add default gw 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 dev eth0SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable`

Comment: You would need a static IP set on your system somewhere between 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.3.254 that is not going to conflict with any of the other IP addresses that are set from 192.168.2.0 through 192.168.2.254.  You would also need to set your netmask to 255.255.252.0.  However, like I said that you would probably end up with routing problems anyway.  The best way to solve this would be to let the IT people that set this up know that it is setup incorrectly.  I still do not know how the router/server let them set up the network that way.

Comment: If you look at this site: https://www.adminsub.net/ipv4-subnet-calculator/192.168.2.0/24  You see that 192.168.2.1 is the FIRST IP address available and 192.168.2.254 is the LAST.  192.168.2.0 should not have ever been allowed to be set to a system IP as it is the network address itself.  They have the network setup incorrectly.

Comment: RFC 1878 does allow usage of addresses with trailing zeroes.

Comment: Yes, it would, if the netmask or subnet of the actual network was at 255.255.252.0 or a /22 network then the range would be 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.3.255 where 192.168.0.0 is the network address with the first starting of 192.168.0.1 and ending at 192.168.3.254, thus allowing 192.168.0.255, 192.168.1.0, 192.168.1.255, 192.168.2.0, 192.168.2.255 and 192.168.3.0 to be valid IP addresses to be used with networking devices.  There is a lot to learn about subnetting.

Comment: This post brings some illumination: https://superuser.com/questions/379451/why-can-a-network-address-not-be-a-valid-host-address
In class C subnets it seems to be allowed to use the "network address" e.g. for the gateway/router. Dhcp client of Ubuntu 18.04 behaves wrong.

Comment: I fully understand that.  What you are missing here is that your Windows computers are getting a network address in a subnet that is 255.255.255.0 and not 255.255.0.0.  The network for Windows is wrong.  I don't know how else to explain this here, so I am done trying to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Well you wont be able to add 192.168.2.0 as a GW if this is a /24 network. In /24 this is network address. Broadcast is at 192.168.2.255. If the router is using this as it's IP then you must have DHCP misconfigured. You probably want a /23 network in this case.

Comment: The dhcp runs fine with Windows 10 laptops, just Ubuntu has problems.

Comment: I want to use 192.168.2.0 as gateway, this has nothing to do with broadcast, does it ?

Comment: Like i said if your network is 192.168.2.0  with subnet 255.255.255.0 the network address is 192.168.2.0. This is not a usable address. I would suggest you fix that. Linux wont allow you to use a network address. If this is part of the larger subnet like a /23 then you would be able to use 192.168.2.0 as a GW. Your usable address space is 192.168.2.1 - 192.168.2.254.

Comment: I don't fully agree in this point. But I will accept your answer to this question as correct if you provide me a script which updates the network configuration of eth0 and ip routes after the dhcp client has setup the connection. I was not able to setup the route yet, how can I get around the error "SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable"?